# Get the list ordered by how many times it appears in another table

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I am using mysql and doctrine2.

I have two tables like these below

User.php

```
ID   name
1    | John
2    | Jonas
3    | Nick
```

Class.php

```
ID  attenduser
1    | 3
2    | 3
3    | 1
4    | 1
5    | 3
6    | 2
```

Class.attenduser is constraint with User.ID

it means Nick attends class three times.
John two times and Jonas one time.

For now I get user list by this doctrine sql

```
SELECT p FROM UserBundle:User p
```

However,I want to get the user list  ordered by how many times he attend the class.

How should I change this?

Acoording to @Palec answer

I made this sentence and try.

```
     SELECT u,COUNT(l.id)
   FROM UserBundle:User u 
    INNER JOIN UserBundle:Class c
   with c.attenduser = u.id group BY u.id 
        ORDER by COUNT(l.id) DESC
```

but it says

```
QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 223: Error: Expected end of string, got '('
```

I think there is something wrong with COUNT though....

I need doctrine information.please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do a sub-select, something like this:

```
SELECT user.name, COUNT(class.id) AS count 
FROM UserBundle:User 
AS user
JOIN UserBundle:Class
AS class
ON class.attenduser = user.id
GROUP BY user.id
ORDER BY count DESC
```

I haven't had a chance to test this so let me know if it fails.

Comment: I got answer from your comment and here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926557/how-to-use-count-and-order-by-count-in-doctorine2 thank you verymuch

Answer (score 1):

Having no experience with Doctrine2 nor any other ORM, I can only show you a solution in plain SQL.

Assuming the first table is named `users` and the second one `classes`. You need to join those tables, count how many times each user attends the class and order the result accordingly.

```
SELECT users.*, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM users JOIN classes ON (users.id = classes.attenduser)
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

I tested this using your example data and it works.