# How to use count and 'order by count()' in Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm

I want to use `ORDERBY COUNT()` sentence in Doctrine.

```
select p.name,count(p.id) from UserBundle:User p Order By count(p.id)
```

But it says.

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 58: Error: Expected end of string, got '('
```

However, with the following code:

```
select p.name,count(p.id) from UserBundle:User p Order By p.name;
```

it works.

Is there something wrong with `Order by count()` on Doctrine? How can I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know doctrine, but when using databases you can usually do something like this:

```
select p.name, count(p.id) AS myCount from UserBundle:User p Order By myCount
```

I just did a quick search on Google and it should work in your case.